# Python subclass uses parent variables in constructor

Tags: python, class

So I'm working on a Text Based RPG and I have a class Item which looks like this:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

Next I have a weapon class which I want to have inherit from the item class, and in the weapon constructor I want it to take the "name" and "value" variables. In my head it works like this:

```
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init(self, name, value, damage):
        self.damage = damage
```

Which I know is wrong, but that's essentially how I think it should work. I've looked up a bunch of threads on the "super()" function, but none of the explanations seem to be doing this. So is this something that's possible or should I just make the weapon class separate? Also... when it does work... what would the constructor call look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as follows inside your `Weapon` class:

```
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, value, damage):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, value)
        self.damage = damage
```

And be sure to use new-style classes, i.e. inherit from `object`:

```
class Item(object):
    ...
```

Comment: I thought in the same solution, but I'm getting a `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` in the line `super...`. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah! I get it now... so basically the super() line takes the arguments from the Weapon __init__ and assigns them to their respective places in the Item __init__... Right?

Comment: Well the `super(...)` call is similar to a Java-`super()` call - it "returns" a handle to the parent class, and thus the result function call is delegated to the parent. In essence, you call the `__init__` function from `Item` manually, passing it the two parameters you got in the `Weapon` `init` call... Got it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, calling the parent class’s constructor is something that you usually need to do:

```
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, value, damage):
        # Initialize the Item part
        Item.__init__(self, name, value)

        # Initialize the Weapon-specific part
        self.damage = damage
```

As for making the weapon class separate—you should read through the article on [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). People have varying opinions on whether inheritance is “right” and in which situations. Sorry that’s so vague, but you haven’t given that much information about your use case :-)

Comment: That's fine! I realize I wasn't totally clear... not all that great at being clear! Anyway, I'll check out the article! Thank you.